# Angular matSort does not sort

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm having trouble with importing matSort into my matTable.

I'm providing you with my code:

**dashboard.component.ts**

```ts
import {Component, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {UserService} from "../user.service";
import {DohvatMantisaService} from "../dohvat-mantisa.service";
import {Mantisi} from "../Mantisi";
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable";
import {DataSource} from "@angular/cdk/collections";
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/startWith';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/merge';
import {MatSort} from '@angular/material';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.css']
})
export class DashboardComponent{
  displayedColumns = ['projekt', 'manits', 'kategorija','ozbiljnost','datum_prijave','postavio','odjel','postavio','naziv','status','planirana_isporuka'];
  constructor(private user:UserService, private dohvatMantisa:DohvatMantisaService) {
  }
  dataSource: TableDataSource | null;
  mantisi: Mantisi[];
  name = this.user.getUsername();
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;
  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataSource = new TableDataSource(this.dohvatMantisa,this.sort);
  }
}

export class TableDataSource extends DataSource<Mantisi>{
  constructor(private mantisiDS: DohvatMantisaService,private sort: MatSort){
    super();
  }
  connect(): Observable<Mantisi[]> {
    const displayDataChanges = [
      this.mantisiDS.dohvatiMantise(),
      this.sort.sortChange,
    ];

    return Observable.merge(...displayDataChanges).map(() => {
      return this.getSortedData();
    });
  }
  disconnect() {}

  getSortedData(): Mantisi[]{
    const data = this.mantisiDS.prikazMantisa().slice();
    if (!this.sort.active || this.sort.direction == '') { return data; }
    return data.sort((a, b) => {
      let propertyA: number|string = '';
      let propertyB: number|string = '';
      switch (this.sort.active) {
        case 'projekt': [propertyA, propertyB] = [a.projekt, b.projekt]; break;
        case 'manits': [propertyA, propertyB] = [a.manits, b.manits]; break;
        case 'kategorija': [propertyA, propertyB] = [a.kategorija, b.kategorija]; break;
        case 'ozbiljnost': [propertyA, propertyB] = [a.ozbiljnost, b.ozbiljnost]; break;
        case 'datum_prijave': [propertyA, propertyB] = [a.datum_prijave, b.datum_prijave]; break;
        case 'postavio': [propertyA, propertyB] = [a.postavio, b.postavio]; break;
        case 'naziv': [propertyA, propertyB] = [a.naziv, b.naziv]; break;
        case 'status': [propertyA, propertyB] = [a.status, b.status]; break;
        case 'planirana_isporuka': [propertyA, propertyB] = [a.planirana_isporuka, b.planirana_isporuka]; break;
      }

      let valueA = isNaN(+propertyA) ? propertyA : +propertyA;
      let valueB = isNaN(+propertyB) ? propertyB : +propertyB;

      return (valueA < valueB ? -1 : 1) * (this.sort.direction == 'asc' ? 1 : -1);
    });
  }
}
```

This is my service:
**dohvatMantisaService**

```ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Response, RequestOptions, Headers} from "@angular/http";
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable";
import {Mantisi} from "./Mantisi";
import 'rxjs';
import 'rxjs/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/operator/do';

@Injectable()
export class DohvatMantisaService {
  constructor(public http:Http) { }
  result: Mantisi[];
  dohvatiMantise(): Observable<Mantisi[]>{
    return this.http.get('/mantis/getMantisReport').map(this.extractData);
  }
  private extractData(response: Response) {
    let body = response.json();
    return body || {};
  }

  prikazMantisa(): Mantisi[]{
    this.dohvatiMantise().subscribe(res => this.result = res);
    return this.result;
  }
}
```

And im providing you with my dashboard.component.html matSort row:

```html
<mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="example-table" matSort>
```

The main problem here is that data is loaded and acquired from http request but I'm getting errors in console something like this:

> Cannot read property 'sortChange' of undefined
> at TableDataSource.webpackJsonp.../../../../../src/app/dashboard/dashboard.component.ts.TableDataSource.connect (dashboard.component.ts:36)
> at MatTable.webpackJsonp.../../../cdk/esm5/table.es5.js.CdkTable._observeRenderChanges (table.es5.js:602)
> at MatTable.webpackJsonp.../../../cdk/esm5/table.es5.js.CdkTable.ngAfterContentChecked (table.es5.js:522)

It tells me that **this.sort.sortChange** is undefined.
I searched all bit of internet and couldn't find proper answer. Hope you can help me with that.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I've found solution for this problem.

The main problem was that table was rendered before data arrived. I've loaded data first and sent it like source to dataSource constructor. After it, problem disappeared. That's the thing with async http.get and services.

Thanks for you help.

```
fetchData(id){
  this.fetch.getProcesses(id).subscribe(result => {
    this.processes = result;
    this.dataSource = new TableDataSource(this.processes);
    Observable.fromEvent(this.filter.nativeElement, 'keyup')
      .debounceTime(150)
      .distinctUntilChanged()
      .subscribe(() => {
        if (!this.dataSource) {
          return;
        }
        this.dataSource.filter = this.filter.nativeElement.value;
      });
  });
}




export class TableDataSource extends DataSource<Proces>{
  _filterChange = new BehaviorSubject('');
  get filter(): string {
    return this._filterChange.value;
  }
  set filter(filter: string) {
    this._filterChange.next(filter);
  }
  filteredData: any =[];

  constructor(private processes:Proces[]){
    super();
  }
  connect(): Observable<Proces[]>{
    const displayDataChanges = [
      this.processes,
      this._filterChange,
    ];
    return Observable.merge(...displayDataChanges).map(() => {
      this.filteredData = this.processes.slice().filter((item: Proces) => {
        const searchStr = (item.name).toLowerCase();
        return searchStr.indexOf(this.filter.toLowerCase()) !== -1;

      });
      return this.filteredData;
    })
  }
  disconnect(){}
}



      <div class="header">
    <mat-form-field floatPlaceholder="never">
      <input matInput #filter placeholder="Pretraži procese">
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>
  <mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="table-mantis" matSort>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="col1">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef class="table-header-cell" mat-sort-header> Name</mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" class="example-cell" > {{row.nazivProcesa}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="col2">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef class="table-header-cell" mat-sort-header> Cell 2</mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" class="example-cell" > {{row.nazivVlasnika
        }} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="col3">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef class="table-header-cell" mat-sort-header> Cell 3</mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" class="example-cell" > {{row.interniAkt}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns" class="example-header-row"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row class="example-row" *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
  </mat-table>
```

Answer (score 116):

If you use "`*ngIf`" to initialy hide the table container in your template, the viewchield will be undefined.

Comment: ¿what can we do if we need a mat-table nested in a node with "*ngIf"?

Comment: You could use a container and make use of  [ngClass]='data !== undefined ?  "visible": "hidden"... the css contains both classes and hide - in case of hidden - the element:
.hidden{
    visibility: hidden;
}

.visible{
    visibility: visible;
}

Comment: is this the desired behaviour of angular2?

Comment: @GustavoAriasMéndez if you really need to hide the table you can just use `[ngClass] = { hidden: <condition> }` instead (assuming you have a hidden class, or are using bootstrap).

Comment: there's a simpler work-around than this [ngClass], just use use [hidden]="<condition>",

Answer (score 74):

I just had this problem, and all I had to do was making sure you're referencing your `matSort viewChild` correctly and make sure you have added the `MatSortModule` in your module.ts file in the imports area.

Like the following:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    MatSortModule,
    MatTableModule,
  ]
)}
```

Comment: It's helpful but it's already imported. Without module import you would get errors like "Have you consider implementing matSort into declaration of @NgModule?". Also, I've posted solution so you can check it.

Comment: Actually, I didn't get any errors without the module import.  It just failed to work because MatSort was undefined at the time I tried to set the `sort` variable.

Comment: Google ain't that good at writing docs such that, by merely following their examples, their code just works. This was my problem. Thanks.

Comment: Just needed to add the MatSortModule to the NgModule imports. After doing that it started working.

Answer (score 19):

I had the same issue and fixed it by adding below:

```
@ViewChild(MatSort) set matSort(ms: MatSort) {
this.sort = ms;
this.setDataSourceAttributes();
 }

@ViewChild(MatPaginator) set matPaginator(mp: MatPaginator) {
 this.paginator = mp;
this.setDataSourceAttributes();
 }

setDataSourceAttributes() {
  this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
  this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  }
```

Comment: This really helped me.  I'm not doing the paginator, but I was having an issue with sorting after a refresh.

Comment: This worked, thanks. For Angular 8 I just had to add options `static: false` - `@ViewChild(MatSort, { static: false }) set matSort(ms: MatSort)`

Comment: { static: false } is missing part when your dataSource is async!

Comment: I am getting error on " this.sort=ms" and "this.paginator=mp.

Comment: This solved my issue. For some reason at the time of ngAfterViewInit my sort was undefined. So the property setter allowed me to capture it when it eventually did get set.

Answer (score 8):

With Angular 8 and Material 6.4.1 if you waiting to receive a data from a service the  simplest and best way to fix the MatSort and MatPaginator is to set the **static: false** instead of true, like this:

```
@ViewChild(MatSort, { static: false }) sort: MatSort;
@ViewChild(MatPaginator, { static: false }) paginator: MatPaginator;
```

In my case is an ngOnChanges call for data.

Comment: Putting `this.dataSource.sort = this.sort` in `ngOnChanges` is what worked for me with an async MatTableDataSource. Also, `{static: false}` is default so you shouldn't have to explicitly declare it.

Answer (score 6):

So it's happening because of your **this.sort.sortChange** method is getting called before your child view Initialize

> You Just need to implement your class from **AfterViewInit** instead of **OnInit**
>
> And use **ngAfterViewInit** life cycle method

```
export class ApplicantListComponent implements AfterViewInit {
    @ViewChild(MatPaginator, { static: false }) paginator: MatPaginator;
    @ViewChild(MatSort, { static: false }) sort: MatSort;

    constructor() {}

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.sort.sortChange.subscribe(() => {
            this.paginator.pageIndex = 0;
            this.paginator.pageSize = this.pageSize;
        });
}
```

Comment: Only your solution helped me. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue when passing async data from a container layer to the component layer. Here's my solution

Because the element started off with no data, there's no use to put a constructor or an OnInit as the **[original example](https://stackblitz.com/angular/gqlnjbagbjg?file=app%2Ftable-overview-example.html)** does. Only After the data stream comes in (async) I implement the sort and paginator in a setter, and everything worked perfectly.

In my template:

```
<div class="card">

    <div class="card-header">
      <h4>{{pageTitle}}</h4>
      <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)" placeholder="Filter">
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>

    <div class="card-body p-0">    
      <div class="mat-elevation-z8">
        <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>

          <ng-container matColumnDef="projectNumber">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Werf Nummer </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> W{{row.projectNumber}} </td>
          </ng-container>

          <ng-container matColumnDef="description">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Omschrijving </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.description}} </td>
          </ng-container>

          <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
          <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;">
          </tr>
        </table>

        <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[10,20,100]"></mat-paginator>
      </div>      
    </div>
  </div>
```

In my angular component class i have

```js
    export class ProjectListComponent {
      pageTitle = 'Projects';
      displayedColumns: string[] = ['projectNumber', 'description'];
      dataSource: MatTableDataSource<Project>;

      @ViewChild(MatPaginator, {static: true}) paginator: MatPaginator;
      @ViewChild(MatSort, {static: true}) sort: MatSort;
      @Input() set projects(value: Project[]){
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(value);
        this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
        this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
      }
      @Input() selectedProject: Project;
      @Output() selected = new EventEmitter<Project>();

      applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
        this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();

        if (this.dataSource.paginator) {
          this.dataSource.paginator.firstPage();
        }
      }
    }
```

I should mention something else that's really interesting about the filtering option. Note that project here only gets used for two fields but the interface is actually more fields than that, for instance it has an ID. Even though I'm not showing the ID, I can filter by ID with the above code which is pretty awesome.

```js
    export interface Project {
        id: string;
        projectNumber: string;
        description: string;
        activePeriods: ProjectActivePeriod[];
    }
```

Also note that it's obligated that the **matColumnDef="projectNumber"** reference in you displayedColumns has to be the exact name of a property in the interface. If I had used '**P**rojectNumber', the sort would not work.

I build this based on the info of

- [example in stackblitz - Data table with sorting, pagination, and
  filtering.](https://stackblitz.com/angular/gqlnjbagbjg?file=app%2Ftable-overview-example.html)
- [documentation on pagination](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview#pagination)

Answer (score 3):

```
<table mat-table matSort #empTbSort="matSort" [dataSource]="dataSource">
```

```
@ViewChild('empTbSort') sort = new MatSort();

 
ngOnInit(): void {
  // async call
  this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<any>(data);
  // make sure to put you sore after init dataSource 
  this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
}
```

**How Mat-table sort works?**
**MatTableDataSource sorts the data by matching the column name(matColumnDef) with the table record property name.**

```
displayedColumns: string[] = ['ID', 'firstname', 'lastname','EmAil'];

export interface Employee 
{
  ID: number,   
  firstname:string, 
  lastname:string,  
  EmAil:string,
}
```

**The property name should match with the matColumnDef, otherwise, the table column will not sort.**

read more: https://www.angularjswiki.com/material/mat-table-sort/

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue,

There are a couple of reasons for this issue

1. Make sure you have included **MatSortModule** module in your **App module**

```
 import { MatSortModule, MatPaginatorModule, MatTableModule } from '@angular/material';

 @NgModule({
  imports: [MatSortModule, MatPaginatorModule, MatTableModule],
  exports: []
})
```

2. Make sure you have subscribed sort change in the **ngAfterViewInit**

```
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.sort.sortChange.subscribe(() => this.paginator.pageIndex = 0 );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to all other answers, if you have multiple tables with sorting in your template, you need to define unique `matSort` as shown below:

Template:

```
<mat-table [dataSource]="firstDataSource" matSort #firstSort="matSort">
```

Component:

```
@ViewChild('firstSort', { static: false }) firstSort: MatSort;

ngAfterViewInit() {
   this.firstDataSource.sort = this.firstSort;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the data is within an object, sorting will not work either. E.g.:

```
interface: Name { firstName: string; lastName: string; }
interface: User { name: Name; }

{{ user.Name.firstName }}
```

Sorting doesn't work in this case. It needs to be flat like: `{{ user.firstName }}`

Additionally the property name and column names must match.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had forgot to put `matSort` prop on `<table/>`.

```
<table mat-table matSort [dataSource]="dataSource">
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, even though I declared

```js
dataSource: MatTableDataSource<MyRowEntity>
```

I was still setting it to an array (which would require an explicit call to matTableChild.renderRows())

```js
// renderRows not called automatically onSortChange
dataSource = [{name: 'hello'}, {name: 'world'}]
```

**Solution:**

```js
// renderRows called automatically onSortChange
this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(myRowEntities);
```

P.S. The original question does not have this error, but I figured others may

Answer (score 0):

I update my data from and external source and for some reason when I changed my `data` variable the table would not update.  I then watched for changes in `ngOnChanges` and updated the `data` variable then, this displayed my table but did not allow me sort.  Here is what finally worked for me:

```
  dataSource: MatTableDataSource<BasicTableData>;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.data);
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    if(changes['data'].currentValue !== changes['data'].previousValue && !changes['data'].firstChange){
      this.dataSource.data = changes['data'].currentValue;
    }
  }
```